# Caching function results using a hashmap scala

Tags: scala, caching, parallel-processing, hashmap

Here is some code I wrote to solve project Euler #14 in scala

The output is shown below as well.  My issue is, I expect better performance from the cached version, but the opposite is true.  I think I did something wrong, since I don't think HashMap's overhead is enough to make this this slow.

Any suggestions?

```
object Problem14 {
def main(args: Array[String]) {
val collatzCacheMap = collection.mutable.HashMap[Long,Long]()

def collatzLengthWithCache(num: Long): Long = {
  def collatzR(currNum: Long, solution: Long): Long = {
    val cacheVal = collatzCacheMap.get(currNum)
    if(cacheVal != None) {
      val answer = solution + cacheVal.get
      collatzCacheMap.put(num, answer);
      answer;
    }
    else if(currNum == 1) { collatzCacheMap.put(num, solution + 1); solution + 1; }
    else if(currNum % 2 == 0) collatzR(currNum/2, solution + 1)
    else collatzR(3*currNum + 1, solution + 1)
  }

  collatzR(num, 0)
}

def collatzLength(num: Long): Long = {
  def collatzR(currNum: Long, solution: Long): Long = {
    if(currNum == 1) solution + 1
    else if(currNum % 2 == 0) collatzR(currNum/2, solution + 1)
    else collatzR(currNum*3 + 1, solution + 1)
  }

  collatzR(num, 0)
}

var startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()

//val answer = (1L to 1000000).reduceLeft((x,y) => if(collatzLengthWithCache(x) > collatzLengthWithCache(y)) x else y)
val answer = (1L to 1000000).zip((1L to 1000000).map(collatzLengthWithCache)).reduceLeft((x,y) => if(x._2 > y._2) x else y)

println(answer)

println("Cached time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime))

collatzCacheMap.clear()

startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()

//val answer2 = (1L to 1000000).par.reduceLeft((x,y) => if(collatzLengthWithCache(x) > collatzLengthWithCache(y)) x else y)
val answer2 = (1L to 1000000).par.zip((1L to 1000000).par.map(collatzLengthWithCache)).reduceLeft((x,y) => if(x._2 > y._2) x else y)

println(answer2)

println("Cached time parallel: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime))

startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()

//val answer3 = (1L to 1000000).reduceLeft((x,y) => if(collatzLength(x) > collatzLength(y)) x else y)
val answer3 = (1L to 1000000).zip((1L to 1000000).map(collatzLength)).reduceLeft((x,y) => if(x._2 > y._2) x else y)

println(answer3)

println("No Cached time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime))

startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()

//val answer4 = (1L to 1000000).par.reduceLeft((x,y) => if(collatzLength(x) > collatzLength(y)) x else y)
val answer4 = (1L to 1000000).par.zip((1L to 1000000).par.map(collatzLength)).reduceLeft((x,y) => if(x._2 > y._2) x else y)

println(answer4)

println("No Cached time parallel: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime))
 }
}
```

Output:

(837799,525) 
Cached time: 1070 
(837799,525) 
Cached time parallel: 954 
(837799,525) 
No Cached time: 450 
(837799,525) 
No Cached time parallel: 241

Comment: How does it scale up? eg. Increase the amount of items in the cached and uncached maps by 10x to reduce the relative overhead of the hashmap implementation, and see if the cached version is still slower.

Comment: First I'm running it with a larger order of magnitude (which is slow, no surprise) and should take a while (if it solves it, Longs might be too small...)

what do you mean increase the amount of items in the cached and uncached maps?  There is only one map for cache and I put every result in it

Comment: The cache time is also slower for 1 to 1 billion

Comment: Sorry, I see waht you mean, I found somewhere the initial size is 16, why isnt that on the documentation?

Comment: So I extended HashMap and override initalSize to ~1M entries(number of entries I'll enter) It didn't change anything...